# How to scan BLE devices that use Extended Advertisement and Coded PHY with Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-ble

I try do create an Android app that scan Bluetooth Low Energy devices that advertise using *Extended Advertisement* and use `Coded PHY` for advertisement.

I have a nrf52840 peripheral that I have setup to advertise using *Extended Advertisement* and `Coded PHY`, so that it can be discovered from long range.

On my Android device, I can discover the nrf52840 peripheral using the **nRF Connect** app.

But I cannot discover the peripheral from my custom Android app.

I have set these `ScanSettings`:

```
    private val scanSettings = ScanSettings.Builder()
        .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_BALANCED)
        .setPhy(ScanSettings.PHY_LE_ALL_SUPPORTED)
        .build()
```

I created a simple `ScanCallback` to log found devices, many are found, but not my peripheral that use `Coded PHY`. I would expect that the nrf52840 peripheral was found.

```
    private val scanCallback = object : ScanCallback() {
        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        override fun onScanResult(callbackType: Int, result: ScanResult?) {
                Log.d("BLE", "found bluetooth device " + result?.device?.address)
        }
    }
```

The scan code is mostly as the code in [Find BLE devices](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/find-ble-devices) but I use my `ScanSettings`:

```
        if (!isScanning) {
            handler.postDelayed({
                isScanning = false
                bleScanner?.stopScan(scanCallback)
            }, SCAN_PERIOD)

            isScanning = true
            bleScanner?.startScan(null, scanSettings, scanCallback)
        } else {
            isScanning = false
            bleScanner?.stopScan(scanCallback)
        }
```

I have set the SDK version to be minimum Android 12.

How can I also find devices on *Extended Advertisement* with `Coded PHY` when scanning BLE devices using Android SDK? They are found on the same device with the *nRF Connect* app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working.

I added [.setLegacy(false)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanSettings.Builder#setLegacy(boolean)) to the `ScanSettings`:

```
    private val scanSettings = ScanSettings.Builder()
        .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_BALANCED)
        .setPhy(ScanSettings.PHY_LE_ALL_SUPPORTED)
        .setLegacy(false)
        .build()
```

and now it found my peripherial that advertise using *Extended Advertisement* and `Coded PHY`.

From the documentation:

> Legacy advertisements include advertisements as specified by the Bluetooth core specification 4.2 and below. This is true by default for compatibility with older apps.

> boolean: true if only legacy advertisements will be returned